# Robot Framework testing that defined headers in data-table are correct

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Im having problem while testing that correct values are present inside data-table  element. Im using Selenium2Library and Robot Framework 3.0 version.

Im using this code to check the values inside  element

```
: FOR    ${item}    IN    @{elements}       INFO        console=yes
\    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    10    1    Element Should Be Visible    
//th[contains(text(),"${item}")]    Header not found: ${item}
```

@{elements} is just a list of column values. It find first two column values and the last value fine when there is no more than one space between the column value. Other column values has spaces and '-' marks. I tried copying the direct value from Developer Console but it didn't help.

Element structure is:

```
<table class="data-table">
<thead><tr class="odd"><th class="top-left" id="col1">Number-one</th> 
<th id="col2">Second-number-column</th>
<th id="col3">Temporary number y-identification</th>
<th id="col4">Temporary numbertwo identification</th>
<th id="col5">Temporary numberthree identification</th>
<th class="top-right" id="col5">Number four</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Cant put the real column data there but its constructed like that. Problematic values are:

```
<th id="col3">Temporary number y-identification</th>
<th id="col4">Temporary numbertwo identification</th>
<th id="col5">Temporary numberthree identification</th>
```

Comment: Can you provide the @{elements} values and perhaps a working example html so that it can be reproduced?

Comment: Updated the html and added @{elements}

Comment: Can you provide the code for creating `@{elements}`. It would make sense if that is not correct. Also be aware that 2+ spaces has a special meaning in Robot.

Comment: Yes, i know it has different meaning. @{elements}  just contains data-table th column element texts separated +2 spaces. Logic works because its finds the two first columns from @{elements} list but stops when Temporary number y-identification comes. I copied the th values straight from the source code. Also tried with different spaces but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try normalizing by space in xpath,

```
: FOR    ${item}    IN    @{elements}       INFO        console=yes
\    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    10    1    Element Should Be Visible    
//th[contains(normalize-space(text()),"${item}")]    Header not found: ${item}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If i use the normalize-space it doesn't find the first two elements that  was found before using the normalize-space.

Comment: You need to change the elements array accordingly. Where u get that element array?

Comment: Element array is from separate variable file. Its just list element containing all the text elements from table header.